# One Model association with two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I have a model 'Match' that belongs to a modell called 'Team'. The Team has many matches. It looks like this:

```
 $class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :home_team, :class_name => "Team"
 belongs_to :away_team, :class_name => "Team"

 class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :matches
```

In the database i have set up properly the two needed fields home_team_id and away_team_id in the 'matches'-table.
I have tried a multiple ways but whenever I do something like this in my match-controller:

```
 @matches = Match.find(:all, :include => :team)
 # Or:
 @matches = Match.where('team.gender = ?', true)
```

I get this error:

```
Association named 'team' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

It seems to me the association does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: match.home_team doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't added any `team` association you have added `home_team` and `away_team` so include home team and away team in your code.or create team association

One more thing how will you  know which one is home team and away team there should be one foreign key needed for home team or and away team and add `foreign_key` in your code to identify them.

Comment: Thanks so far. When I try this in the controller:  `code @matches = Match.find(:all, :joins =>[:home_team], :select =>'team_name')`
I get the name of the associated model 'Team'. But is it possible to get both :home_team and away_team in one query? When I try i get a "Column 'team_name' in field list is ambiguous"-error-message.

Comment: i am not understood your query but as per my guess create 2 methods home_team_name and away_team_name or you can use `delegate` which can helpful

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking too complicate. I only want to fetch the names of both away and home-team from the team-table together with the match-scores

Comment: Did the query this way now, it works. Pls. let me know if there's a better way to to do it: `Match.all(:joins => 'INNER JOIN teams AS first_team
ON first_team.id = matches.home_team_id INNER JOIN 
teams AS second_team ON second_team.id = matches.away_team_id',
:select => 'home_team_id, first_team.team_name AS first_team,
home, away, matchdate, matchtime, second_team.team_name AS second_team, played'`